# Highlight menu items when using ScrollTo and LocalScroll plugins

Tags: jquery, scrollto

I am using the [ScrollTo](http://flesler.blogspot.co.uk/2007/10/jqueryscrollto.html) and [LocalScroll](http://flesler.blogspot.co.uk/2007/10/jquerylocalscroll-10.html) plugins to apply nice scrolling to anchor navigation on [this site](http://p3rpublicity.com/wordpress/).

What I would like is to always have correct menu item highlighted as the user scrolls with the scroll bar.

I have seen this [question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8393442/highlight-active-link-when-using-scrollto-based-on-current-view) but I'm afraid I can't figure out how to modify it successfully! (My navigation uses `#about`, `#contact` etc rather than `#section`, `#section2` etc, but I have given each section a name of `section1`, `section2` etc like in the example)

I have also tried the [One Page Navigation](http://trevordavis.net/blog/jquery-one-page-navigation-plugin/) plugin which comes with this functionality be default, but it conflicts with my dropdown menu :(

Thanks for taking the time to read this. Hope you can help!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to generalize your code to do the same thing both when you are visiting `#section1` through an external link, and internally throught `<a href="#section1">Section 1</a>`, you can listen to the `hashchange` event. It won't update while scrolling though, but if you generalize the code and make it reusable, I'm sure it's easy to combine the techniques.

Try [Ben Alman's jQuery hashchange event plugin](http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-hashchange-plugin/) and add a callback calling the same function. You might want to use it together with [jQuery urlInternal: Easily test URL internal-, external-, or fragment-ness](http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-urlinternal-plugin/) and perhaps [jQuery BBQ: Back Button & Query Library](http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-bbq-plugin/), also by Ben Alman.

Here's some code, quickly adapted from a project where I use it in the same way to activate different tabs in a tab row. (I use all three plugins mentioned above, but I don't remember if all of them were necessary for this snippet.)

```
(function() {
    var menuLinksSelector = "#menu-main-menu a",
        menuLinkHighlightClass = "current";

    $.fn.extend({
        filterLinksToFragment: function(fragment) {
            var $this = $(this),
                $filtered = $this.filter("a:urlFragment").filter(function() {
                    var $this = $(this),
                        thisFragment = $.param.fragment($this.attr('href'));

                    return (thisFragment === fragment);
                });

            return $filtered;
        }
    });

    function highlightMenuItem(fragment) {
        var $menuLinks = $(menuLinksSelector),
            $selectedMenuLink = $menuLinks.filterLinksToFragment(fragment);

        $menuLinks.removeClass(menuLinkHighlightClass);
        $menuItem.addClass(menuLinkHighlightClass);
    }

    function highlightCurrentMenuItem() {
        var currentFragment = $.param.fragment();

        if (currentFragment !== undefined && currentFragment !== "") {
            highlightMenuItem(currentFragment);
        }
    }

    $window.on('hashchange', function() {
        // Activate the current URL's #part-anything link
        highlightCurrentMenuItem();
    });

    // Trigger the event (useful on page load).
    $window.hashchange();
}());
```

if you use this code, you won't need to use the `.click(...)` handler you have in your question, except perhaps to cancel the click event, since you have plugins for scrolling.

Comment: Thanks Joel! However my #anchor navigation is working well, so ideally I would just like to use a script that highlights a menu item based on the scroll position, not hash in the URL. I have modified my question to hopefully make this clearer.