# how to change menu background color when selected?

Tags: jquery, css

I started learning CSS these days, currently i was given with one CSS task, i've tried but iam not getting it..

**here is my requirement:**

```
The site is http://mywebsite.com/ .
```

You will notice the the menu bar has a hover the color is `#1B3E70` .
          That's the color I want to the selected menu bar item to display when the on the corresponding area/page.

**I tried as below but not getting:**

```
 a:visited{
    background: #1B3E70;
}
```

please suggest me..

Comment: possible duplicate of [Highlight current page in jquery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2955851/highlight-current-page-in-jquery)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**With Reference to your link (classes and id) :**

HTML

```
<li class="menu-item">
    <a href="#">About</a>
    <a href="#">Home</a>
</li>
```

CSS

```
 .menu-item{
        list-style:none;
    } 
    .menu-item a{
        padding:20px;
        padding-bottom:10px;
        border:1px solid #1B3E70;
        color:#1B3E70;
        text-decoration:none;
    }.menu-item a:hover{
            background-color:#1B3E70;
        color:white;
    }
    .menu-item .active{
         background-color:#1B3E70;
         color:white;

    }
```

Jquery

```
    $('.menu-item a').click(function(){
    $(this).addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
    });
```

Live Example http://jsfiddle.net/7VBy9/

Comment: hey, i tried your code, BUT still not getting required output.. please suggest me what went wrong..?

Comment: currently, whatever menu clicked, its getting selected with desired color, but color still remaining on that tab.

Comment: The reason is You have to remove the style/class from the other tab while one is selected which was achieved via siblings !

Comment: Can you please tell me which class/style should remove?

Comment: The .active class my friend :)

Answer (score 0):

The background-color on a:visited only seems to work in FF, Chrome and Safari. if the normal a has a background-color, either explicitly defined or through inherit (the direct parent must actually have a background-color for this to be true).

Obviously it is not ideal to have to define a background-color for a all the time, as the site may have a background image.

Comment: so, what changes I need to do?

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14202856/background-image-for-visited-links

Answer (score 0):

If you means highlight the current menu text when it's clicked, then you can try to use this code:

```
$(function() {
     $('#nav li').click(function() {
         $(this).find('a').addClass('active');
          $(this).siblings('li').find('a').removeClass('active');
     })
});
```

and add `.active` in your css:

```
.active {
    background: #1B3E70;
}
```

Comment: Ideally, but I am not the OP, it would also highlight on scroll down to those content `div`s. This should do it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8393442/highlight-active-link-when-using-scrollto-based-on-current-view

Comment: @Felix : Do I really need to use some jquery here? is that not possible to do with some CSS settings?

Comment: @user3128668 There is no way you can achieve the same effect using pure CSS, the `:visited` pseudo class is not applicable in your case.

Comment: @jammykam Absolutely, since OP using one-page navigation.

Comment: @Felix i tried your code, but not required output.. i even tried above code ie., user3011961 , even that also not working.. currently iam using user3011961 code, i think his code is also correct as he showned  output in his fiddle, can you please suggest me still what went wrong with his code?

Comment: user3218668's code seems working for me, BUT prob is: currently, whatever menu clicked, its getting selected with desired color, but color still remaining on that tab.

So, could you please tell me what need to change code in his function?

Answer (score 0):

Try,

```
jQuery(function(){
 jQuery('#nav li a').click(function() {
 jQuery('#nav li a').removeClass('active');
 jQuery(this).addClass('active');
 });
});
```

Also add following css to your file

```
.links a.active {
    color: #FFFFFF;
    background-color: #1B3E70;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try using this for changing the color.

```
a:visited {color: #1B3E70;}
```