# How to change the Menu colour when selected?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net, css

I have created a menu in my asp.net website and I want the active Menu item in the menu to be highlighted when it is clicked. That is usually the menu is White but when the user choose any of the menu then it should become red. Please find below what I have tried so far:

Jquery:

```
 <head runat="server">
   <script type="text/javascript">
    $('.thumbnail').click(function (e) {
        $('.thumbnail').removeClass('selected');
        $(this).addClass('selected');
    });
  </script>
 <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="head" runat="server">
 </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</head>
```

aspx page:

```
 <div id="nav">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="Default.aspx" class="thumbnail">Dashboard</a> //I want this
               menu option to be Red when in the Dashboard page.

                <ul>
                    <a href="Default.aspx" class="hover">
                        <li>Servie Details</li>
                    </a><a href="Dashboard_totalusersDaily.aspx" class="hover">
                        <li>Subscribers History</li>
                    </a><a href="WhiteList.aspx" class="hover">
                        <li>Whitelist </li>
                    </a>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="mnggroup.aspx" class="thumbnail">Subscribers</a> //I want this
              Subscrivers Menu Option to be Red when user is in this page
                <ul>
                    <a href="mnggroup.aspx" class="hover">
                        <li>Group</li>
                    </a>
                    <a href="#" class="hover">
                        <li>Subscribers Chart</li>
                    </a>
                    <a href="#" class="hover">
                        <li>Subscribers Chart by Date </li>
                    </a>
                    <a href="#" class="hover">
                        <li>Inactive Subscribers Chart</li>
                    </a>
                </ul>

            </li>
      </div>
```

CSS:

```
     .thumbnail {
    display: block;
    line-height: 2.5em;
    margin-right: 0px;
    padding: 8px 14px 8px 14px;
    color: #3d3737;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 0.8em;
    text-decoration: none;
  }

  #nav ul li .selected {
    color: #ffffff;
    background-color: transparent;
    background-image: url(../Img/navaktiv.jpg);
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
}
```

I got this above code idea from this link: [how to change menu background color when selected?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21225745/how-to-change-menu-background-color-when-selected)

After trying this above code all of my menu items remaining white. When I choose any option it is not becoming red. Please help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem is in your CSS. You have added space between "li" and class "selected".
It should be `"#nav ul li.selected"`.

And at the same time add your code inside `$(document).ready()` function
Add below mention code in HTMl "head"

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>    
<script type="text/javascript">  
    $( document ).ready(function() {  
        $('.thumbnail').click(function (e) {  
            $('.thumbnail').removeClass('selected');  
            $(this).addClass('selected');  
        });  
    });  
</script>
```

Add this at bottom of CSS :-

```
#nav ul li.selected {  
    color: #ffffff;  
    background: url(../Img/navaktiv.jpg) repeat-x red;  
}
```

Comment: Please use [Editing Help](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) and format your answer to be more readable.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. But it is not working. I don't what is wrong in here with my code. when I try this link example: http://learn.yancyparedes.net/2012/05/jquery-highlighting-the-menu-item-for-the-current-page/ it is working. But then it is highlighting even the submenu's what I don't want. I want to highlight only the main menu. Thank you.

Comment: Colud you share screen shot here with "li.thumbnail" in clicked condition with fireebug open

Comment: Check below mentioned link. Hope this is what you needed.
http://jsfiddle.net/L69tt/

Answer (score 0):

Because you have not set background color to red in style for selected:

```
#nav ul li .selected {
  color: #ffffff;
  background-color: red;
  background-image: url(../Img/navaktiv.jpg);
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
}
```

**Update:**

Ensure that you have added the click handler in DOM ready:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
    $('.thumbnail').click(function (e) {
        $('.thumbnail').removeClass('selected');
        $(this).addClass('selected');
    });
 });
```

Comment: sorry for my mistake. Actually the Background image is already red so I am expecting it to accept the background image. Thank you.

Comment: have you checked whether cass selected is getting added to selected element.

Comment: yes I have tried. It is calling CSS class properly. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Since you put your jQuery code in the `<head>` section, try to wrap them inside **[DOM ready](http://api.jquery.com/ready/)** handler.

```
$(function() {
    $('.thumbnail').click(function (e) {
        $('.thumbnail').removeClass('selected');
        $(this).addClass('selected');
    });
});
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. But I am quite new in Jquery so I am not so clear about DOM. Will you explain a little bit about it.

Comment: Did you check the docs from the link that I've provided in my answer?

Comment: A page can't be manipulated safely until the document is "ready." jQuery detects this state of readiness for you. Code included inside $( document ).ready() will only run once the page Document Object Model (DOM) is ready for JavaScript code to execute.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I have tried but no hope yet.

Comment: But when I try from this link example: http://learn.yancyparedes.net/2012/05/jquery-highlighting-the-menu-item-for-the-current-page/ it works. But it is changing the color for the Sub-Menu too. But I need it for Main Menus only. Will you please help on that? Thank you.

Comment: well my problem is the menu color is not changing at all. I want the menu selected will be in another colour. But it is not happening.

Comment: http://learn.yancyparedes.net/2012/05/jquery-highlighting-the-menu-item-for-the-current-page/

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $( document ).ready(function() {
        $('.thumbnail').click(function (e) {
            $('.thumbnail').removeClass('selected');

            // How about using some troubleshooting code while you're developing this?
            console.log($(this));                
            console.log($(this).attr('class'));
            $(this).addClass('selected');
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Then double-check your CSS code and put a break point on your debugger (e.g., FF's Firebug) and check how your anchor tag reacts to the changes, line-by-line.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Yes I have tried to check using Firebug and found that it is going to the CSS code properly. But when I try from this link example: http://learn.yancyparedes.net/2012/05/jquery-highlighting-the-menu-item-for-the-current-page/ it works. But it is changing the color for the Sub-Menu too. But I need it for Main Menus only. Will you please help on that? Thank you.